# How to create a customized catalina.jar?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I am using tomcat 6.0.18 for my web project, where we have **customized** the tomcat and created a **catalina.jar**.  Now again we are going to upgrade the tomcat6 to ***tomcat 7.0.40*** where the same customization is needed.  I have made the changes but I dont know how to convert it to  catalina.jar, also I would like to know, what type of jar is catalina jar.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: just wanted ask one thing. after creating catalina.jar, what do you with it or what changes you do? any performance change or anything else?

Comment: actually the change is regarding the cookie, i have 3 services in the project which could be selected by a dropdown, even if a user changes the service it should be saved in the same cookie only.

Comment: Your question is meaningless. There is only one type of JAR file. I strongly suggest that you take the opportunity to find a way to do what you want without modifying Tomcat. Otherwise you're going to have this problem forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have did this by, extracting the source zip and imported it as a project in eclipse. Then added the following codes to request.java, to configure session cookie :

```
protected void configureSessionCookie(Cookie cookie)
  {
     cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
    String contextPath = null;
    if(!connector.getEmptySessionPath() && getContext() != null)
        contextPath = getContext().getEncodedPath();
    if(contextPath != null && contextPath.length() > 0)
        cookie.setPath(contextPath);
    else
        cookie.setPath("/");
    if(isSecure())
        cookie.setSecure(true);
    String domain = this.getServerName();
      if (domain != null)    
    {
        domain = domain.substring(domain.indexOf('.')+1);
        cookie.setDomain(domain);
    }
}
```

So that my cookie remains unchanged when I change the service, it gets destroyed only if i logout of the session.

After changing the code, to create a customized jar we can make use of jar.exe given by java. In cmd prompt run ***jar.exe*** and then use ***jar cvf catalina.jar c://location_of_folder*** and you can get the customized catalina.jar in java bin folder